# C# .Net Core Blazor Unable to register a service with a constructor. There is no registered service of type

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor

I am updating a project to use interfaces.

I have an interface called **IEmployeeService**.

```cs
public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        List<Employee> GetEmployees();
    }
```

I have a service which implements this interface. BUT the service also has a constructor

```cs
public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        private IDbConnection db;

        public EmployeeService(string connString)
        {
            this.db = new SqlConnection(connString);
        }

        public List<Employee> GetEmployees(bool activeOnly = false)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

If I register the service in Startup.cs without mentioning the interface like so, then it works fine

```cs
services.AddTransient<EmployeeService>(_ => new EmployeeService(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

When I register it using the interface instead like so. I then get the error reported as seen below.

```cs
services.AddTransient<IEmployeeService>(_ => new EmployeeService(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'EmployeeServ' on type 'RolesAndSecurityMatrix.SSBlazorUI.Pages.SearchByEmployee'. There is no registered service of type 'RolesAndSecurityMatrix.DataAccess.EmployeeService'.

Note: this is a Blazor Server-side app and these services mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as I finished writing the question, it dawned on me that I didn't update my blazor components to inject the interface version of the service as well.

So in a component which used the EmployeeService, it looked like this

```cs
[Inject] EmployeeService EmployeeServ { get; set; }
```

And once I changed it to this, it then worked

```cs
[Inject] IEmployeeService EmployeeServ { get; set; }
```

Comment: I ran into similar trouble. The answer just helped.

Comment: How did you get Configuration? It is impossible to get it before app.Build()

Comment: @Dmitry - if you are using the newer .NET5 or above then you can simply get to configuration using the builder that is in your Program.cs

Like build.Configuration.GetConnectionString("");